# Merge lines between pattern

Tags: sed

I have a large file (~20GB) that I need to parse. I need to merge all lines that don't start with an integer. The file look's like this:

```
     1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
     1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
     1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
            dolores eos qui ratione
       quia non numquam eius
         nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
     1820 zt enim ad minim veniam
```

In the end I need it to look like this:

```
     1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
     1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
     1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem dolores eos qui ratione quia non numquam eius nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
     1820 zt enim ad minim veniam
```

I tried a lot of things, for example:

With a registry ... works great on smaller files, on large files it runs out of memory

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n[\t ]*\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/ \1/g'
```

Using Hold buffer (this prints just the lines that start with integer):

```
sed -n '
/^[ \t]\+[0-9]\+/ {
    p
    h
}
/^[ \t]\+[0-9]\+/ !{
    H
}
'
```

or:

```
sed -n '
/^[ \t]\+[0-9]\+/ b jumpTO
        H
        $ b jumpTO
        b
:jumpTO
x
p
'
```

It misses the code for replacing the space and tab from lines without integers, they are not important and are trivial to implement.

Please take a look at the code and point what I am doing wrong.
**Thank you**

Comment: Remove all newlines, replace numbers with "\n{number}"?  Of course that would only work if you have no numbers in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is impossible with `sed` =)

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]/{x;p};/^[^0-9]/{H;x;s/\n\s*\([^0-9]\)/ \1/;x};${x;p}'
```

```
1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem dolores eos qui ratione quia non numquam eius nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
1820 zt enim ad minim veniam
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is generally not very good at combining lines together, as it is designed to work on a per-line basis.

A solution using `awk` might be better:

input.txt:

```
$ cat input.txt
1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
       dolores eos qui ratione
  quia non numquam eius
    nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
1820 zt enim ad minim veniam
```

script.awk:

```
/^[0-9]+/ {
    if (NR==1) {
        printf "%s", $0
    } else {
        printf "\n%s", $0
    }
}

/^[^0-9]+/ {
    gsub(/^ /,"",$0);
    gsub(/ $/,"",$0);
    printf "%s", $0
}

END {
    printf "\n"
}
```

output:

```
$ awk -f script.awk input.txt
1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatemdolores eos qui rationequia non numquam eiusnisi ut aliquid ex ea com
1820 zt enim ad minim veniam
```

**Update: improved code to remove whitespace**

Answer (score 1):

does this one-liner help? (awk)

```
 awk '$1~/[0-9]+/{printf "\n"$0;next}{printf $0}' yourfile
```

**test**

```
kent$  cat test.txt
1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
       dolores eos qui ratione
  quia non numquam eius
    nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
1820 zt enim ad minim veniam

kent$  awk '$1~/[0-9]+/{printf "\n"$0;next}{printf $0}' test.txt

1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem       dolores eos qui ratione  quia non numquam eius    nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
1820 zt enim ad minim veniam
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this will work for you:

`->nawk '{if($1~"^[a-zA-Z]"){p=p" "$0;flag=1}else{if(flag==1)print p;p=$0;print p;flag=0}}' temp`

```
> cat temp
1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
dolores eos qui ratione
quia non numquam eius
nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
1820 zt enim ad minim veniam

> nawk '{if($1~"^[a-zA-Z]"){p=p" "$0;flag=1}else{if(flag==1)print p;p=$0;print p;flag=0}}' temp
1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem dolores eos qui ratione quia non numquam eius nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
1820 zt enim ad minim veniam

>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '/[0-9]/ { if (line) print line; line = $0; next } { sub(/^[ \t]+/, " "); line = line $0 } END { print line }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
     1647 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
     1906 ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
     1909  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem dolores eos qui ratione quia non numquam eius nisi ut aliquid ex ea com
     1820 zt enim ad minim veniam
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n\s*\([^0-9 ]\)/ \1/;ta;P;D' file
```